# GPU underutilized training a CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras

What I'm trying to do is retrain VGG16 on recognizing new types of Image data using Keras with Tensorflow backend.

But the training process seems very slow to me, and after checking my GPU performance in the task manager it seems to me like my GPU is barely even being utilized.

This is my code: https://hastebin.com/pepozayutu.py

This is the output in my console: https://hastebin.com/uhonugenej.md

And this is what my task manager looks like during training: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdc4I.jpg

As you can see the GPU is barely doing anything, so why is my training so slow? It's agonizing to try different setups because each training takes 20-60 min depending on number of epochs.

I have installed Tensorflow-gpu 1.7.0, cuDNN 7.0.5, CUDA 9.0 and Keras 2.1.5. I'm running an NVIDIA GeForce 940MX

edit: **I solved it**! It appears that the problem was that my GPU was only being used for very short periods, and the reason for that was that the bottleneck was actually loading in the images. I stored my images as 3000x4000 pixel jpgs even though I scale them down to 150x150 or sometimes 64x64 for the CNN anyway. Reducing the size of my images on my disk seemed to get rid of the bottleneck

Comment: Which laptop are you using?

Comment: For completeness, what's your CPU utilisation?

Comment: @PhilipCouling I posted it in the imgur album along with my GPU utilisation. It bounces between ~25-50%

Comment: @Lcukerd a lenovo thinkpad t470p

Comment: If you solved your own problem, post the solution **as an answer**, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! It appears that the problem was that my GPU was only being used for very short periods, and the reason for that was that the bottleneck was actually loading in the images. I stored my images as 3000x4000 pixel jpgs even though I scale them down to 150x150 or sometimes 64x64 for the CNN anyway. Reducing the size of my images on my disk seemed to get rid of the bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

Increase your batch size to, say, 512. Batch size of 30 is too small.

Comment: I've increased it to 150, if I use too big batch size I will get OOM errors. It seems like now it uses more of my memory but its very spiky. It uses a lot of memory for a short time each step and then there's a long pause. https://imgur.com/dkpPXgE

Answer (score 0):

The new TF.data.dataset API is great for building pieplines that feed data to your model asynchronously. So while your graph is being computed the pipeline will prefetch the data ready to go when the next graph execution cycle starts. With tf.estimators you can run a keras model with a TF.data.dataset pipeline as well. An example:

https://www.dlology.com/blog/an-easy-guide-to-build-new-tensorflow-datasets-and-estimator-with-keras-model/